# Apache cannot parse PHP after installation of apache2.4 and PHP7.2.29

Tags: php, linux, apache

I installed apache2.4 and PHP7.2.29 on Manjaro. After the installation, apache could not parse PHP. I compiled and installed PHP with source code, and installed apache with pacman package.

```sh
➜  ~ sudo systemctl status httpd
[sudo] achuan 的密码：
● httpd.service - Apache Web Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disable>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-04-02 03:59:57 EDT; 55s ago
    Process: 53105 ExecStart=/usr/bin/httpd -k start -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FA>
   Main PID: 53105 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 02 03:59:57 achuanPC systemd[1]: Started Apache Web Server.
Apr 02 03:59:57 achuanPC httpd[53105]: [Thu Apr 02 03:59:57.822896 2020] [php7:crit] [pid 5>
Apr 02 03:59:57 achuanPC httpd[53105]: AH00013: Pre-configuration failed
Apr 02 03:59:57 achuanPC systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, statu>
Apr 02 03:59:57 achuanPC systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.


LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp72.so
Include conf/extra/php72_module.conf

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps    
    #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    #AddHandler type-map var
    #AddType text/html .shtml
    #AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html 
</IfModule>


As long as this code is written into the apache configuration, apache will not start

LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp72.so
```

I'm sure both libphp72.so and php72_module.conf exist

Who can help me to solve, I am very grateful!